# how to pause and stop calculation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some calculation that I will show you in codes. I know how to start this calculation but I don't have any idea how to pause and stop during calculation let me write the code so that easy for you to understand.

***.m file***

```
@interface ViewController (){
float f;
}
@property double result;
@end

 @implementation ViewController
 @synthesize textLabel;
 @synthesize TimeLabel;

 -(void)calculatingPIValue{
 NSDate *methodStart = [NSDate date];
    int r[2800 + 1];
    int i,k;
    int b;
    int d;
    double c = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < 2800; i++) {

        r[i] = 20000; }
    for ( k = 2800; k > 2790; k -= 14){

        d = 0;
        i = k;
        for (;;) {
            d += r[i] * 10000;

            b = 2 * i - 1;
            r[i] = d % b;
            d /= b;
            i--;
            if (i == 0) break;
            d *= i;
        }
        f = ((c + d) / 10000000)/10;
         NSLog(@"the value is %.09f",f);
    }
    self.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.08f",f];
    NSDate *methodFinish = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval executionTime = [methodFinish      timeIntervalSinceDate:methodStart];
    NSLog(@"executionTime = %f", executionTime);
    TimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",executionTime];

    });
- (IBAction)startButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender{

  [self calculatingPIValue];


  }


  - (IBAction)pauseButton:(UIButton *)sender {
  }

  - (IBAction)stopButton:(UIButton *)sender {
  }
  @end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to refactor this code to operate in the background. I suggest using GCD and dispatch_async. You can write it to check the value of a boolean instance variable (abort) and return when stop == YES.

Something like this:

```
@interface ViewController (){
float f;
}
//---------------------------------
//This is new
@property (atomic, assign) BOOL abort; 
//---------------------------------
@property double result;
@end

 @implementation ViewController
 @synthesize textLabel;
 @synthesize TimeLabel;


 -(void)calculatingPIValue
  {
    NSDate *methodStart = [NSDate date];
    int r[2800 + 1];
    int i,k;
    int b;
    int d;
    double c = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < 2800; i++) {

        r[i] = 20000; }
    for ( k = 2800; k > 2790; k -= 14){

        d = 0;
        i = k;
        for (;;) {
            //---------------------------------
            //This is the new code
            if (self.abort)
              return;
            //---------------------------------
            d += r[i] * 10000;

            b = 2 * i - 1;
            r[i] = d % b;
            d /= b;
            i--;
            if (i == 0) break;
            d *= i;
        }
        f = ((c + d) / 10000000)/10;
         NSLog(@"the value is %.09f",f);
    }
    self.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.08f",f];
    NSDate *methodFinish = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval executionTime = [methodFinish      timeIntervalSinceDate:methodStart];
    NSLog(@"executionTime = %f", executionTime);
    TimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",executionTime];

  }

- (IBAction)startButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
  {
    //---------------------------------
    //This code is changed
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH), ^
    {
      [self calculatingPIValue];
    });
    //---------------------------------
  }


  - (IBAction)pauseButton:(UIButton *)sender {
  }

  - (IBAction)stopButton:(UIButton *)sender 
  {
     self.abort = TRUE;
  }
  @end
```

That's the basic idea. Pausing and then resuming the calculations would be a whole lot more complicated.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the `});` at the end of the first method. Looks like passing a block to a function, but can't find the beginning. Also, the closing `}` for that method's body seems to be missing...?

Comment: There was a missing comma and an extra close paren in the call to dispatch_async. This wasn't meant to be debugged code - more like pseudocode to give you the idea.

Comment: It is indeed passing a block to the function dispatch_async.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But I can't find the call to `dispatch_async` inside `-calculatingPIValue`.

Comment: There isn't a call to dispatch_async inside `calculatingPIValue`. It's the other way around. `calculatingPIValue` is called from inside a call to `dispatch_async`. That way the `calculatingPIValue` can return when `abort == TRUE`.

Comment: That's what I thought. Still, can't make heads or tails of this segment of your code: `...});  - (IBAction)startButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89629/discussion-between-duncan-c-and-nicolasmiari).

Comment: its not stopping calculation.. any other idea?